# Can I get job in MNC without 9 months exp. certificate of last company and with 6 years exp. certificates of previous companies?

Tags: hiring-process, work-experience, india, termination, certification

## Problem

I am a java developer with 7 years experience. In India, I worked in 4 IT companies. I have 6 years exp. with exp. certificates of previous companies. I have 9 months experience in 4th company without experience certificate. 4th company did not provide experience certificate, the reason is I disagreed the new rule "based on project completion, the salary will be provided" which was
created in the 4th company on January 2016. As I disagreed the new rule, the 4th company terminated me from the services and denied to provide experience certificate. In 4th company, I have 9 months experience in 4th company.

## Questions

I am in job hunting in India. I apply jobs in multi-national companies like TCS, CTS, HCL etc.,.

- Can I apply to MNC companies by telling the truth about 4th company not providing experience certificate as opposed new rule "based on project completion, the salary will be provided"?
- can I apply to MNC companies by telling the 9 months gap, not working but studying?
- can I apply to MNC companies by getting experience certificate from 4th company through Police?
- If I approach police to get experience certificate, will MNC find me any records about me in Police station? If any records related to this experience certificate issue found by MNC, will MNC deny me to hire?

What must I do to be hired in MNC company like HCL, CTS, TCS,Tech Mahindra, etc., in the right way?

Can I get job in MNC(HCL,CTS,etc.,) without 9 months experience certificate of last company and with 6 years experience certificates of previous companies?

Comment: Your whole question boils down to what to do about a missing certificate. I suggest you get a lawyer and **get** the certificate.

Comment: @nvoigt - I think it's related but not the same, but boils down to 'get a lawyer' so off topic.

Comment: You have asked this before and it got closed.  Re-post with nicer formatting does not make it a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get a job. Do not worry about this before interviews. When you get selected and have the experience verification process you can deal with it then.

You can provide the income tax returns/salary slips  as proof if needed. Also some MNCs accept joining letter. Usually the verification personnel do all the verification by email/phone. You can tell them that you don't have the experience letter ( do not tell the reason ). They usually ask if you can provide any other proof ( salary slip / income tax record from company )

Comment: Thanks a lot, so kind of you. What should I tell If they ask reason for not having experience letter from the previous company.

Comment: Like i said they will not ask you if you provide with an other proof. If they do ask , you can say the co has refused to give it to me due to certain differences when you left the organization. You don't need to elaborate.